# order by min() in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, min

I am new to oracle sql. I'm trying to understand the following code. Can anyone explain, in simple terms, how min(amt) sorts the results in asc order? I thought min() returns one value. Why does max(amt) give the exact same results? Sorting by min() gives the results I want, but trying to understand how it does it.

```
select (case when amt > 200 then '>200'
             when amt > 100 then  '>100'
          else '>50'
        end)
count(distinct orderno)
from xyz
where order_date between '...' and sysdate
group by (case when amt > 200 then '>200'
             when amt > 100 then  '>100'
          else '>50'
        end)
order by min(amt)

Result:
> 50
>100
>200
```

Comment: You have a group by clause in that query, otherwise, you should get `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`. Please show your actual query if not too long -- or come with some test case we can investigate.

Comment: `min(amt)` is ordering by the minimum value of `amt` in whatever group you have specified.  I think you might be getting `min` and `max` confused with sort direction (`asc` and `desc`).

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to order the results by the groupings.  The values are:

- `'>50'`
- `'>100'`
- `'>200'`

In fact, the above would be the "natural" ordering for them.  However, the ordering by the database would be alphabetical, and hence:

- `'>100'`
- `'>200'`
- `'>50'`

In order to get the bins in the right order, a sample value is needed from each bin (the bins are disjoint so any value will do).  By taking the minimum, the resulting bins are in the right order.

By the way, you could order by the bins if they were zero padded on the left:

- `'>050'`
- `'>100'`
- `'>200'`

Then the alphabetical ordering would match the intuitive ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following - you'll want to order by a numeric column in order to get the results you want:

```
SELECT '>'||round_amt AS result, order_cnt FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN amt > 200 THEN 200 WHEN amt > 100 THEN 100 ELSE 50 END AS round_amt
         , COUNT(DISTINCT orderno) AS order_cnt
      FROM xyz
     WHERE order_date BETWEEN '...' AND SYSDATE
     GROUP BY CASE WHEN amt > 200 THEN 200 WHEN amt > 100 THEN 100 ELSE 50 END
) ORDER BY round_amt
```